# i made the gui program for a calculator but i want to show a confirm messgae in java if the value in the textfield is a string

Tags: java

```
public class x extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JFrame calc;
    JPanel holder;
    JTextField zzz;
    JLabel updating;
    JButton a, s, m, d, c;
    float input, ans;
    String lol, n;
    boolean f = true;
    JOptionPane p;

    public x() {
        ans = 0;
        calc = new JFrame("CALCULATOR");
        calc.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 5));
        calc.setVisible(true);
        calc.setSize(1000, 2000);

        holder = new JPanel();
        holder.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 5));
        holder.setVisible(true);

        zzz = new JTextField();
        zzz.addActionListener(this);

        updating = new JLabel(ans + " ");


        a = new JButton("ADD");
        a.addActionListener(this);
        a.setEnabled(true);

        s = new JButton("SUBTRACT");
        s.addActionListener(this);
        s.setEnabled(true);

        m = new JButton("MULTIPLY");
        m.addActionListener(this);
        m.setEnabled(true);

        d = new JButton("DIVISION");
        d.addActionListener(this);
        d.setEnabled(true);

        c = new JButton("CLEAR");
        c.addActionListener(this);
        c.setEnabled(true);

        holder.add(a, BorderLayout.WEST);
        holder.add(s, BorderLayout.WEST);
        holder.add(m, BorderLayout.WEST);
        holder.add(d, BorderLayout.WEST);
        holder.add(c, BorderLayout.WEST);

        calc.add(updating, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        calc.add(zzz, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        calc.add(holder, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lol = zzz.getText();
        input = Float.parseFloat(lol);

        if (e.getSource() == zzz) {
            n = zzz.getText();

        } else if (e.getSource() == a) {

            ans = input + ans;
            updating.setText(ans + " ");
            zzz.setText("0 ");

        } else if (e.getSource() == s) {

            ans = ans - input;
            updating.setText(ans + " ");
            zzz.setText("0 ");

        } else if (e.getSource() == d) {

            ans = ans / input;
            updating.setText(ans + " ");
            zzz.setText(" 0");

        } else if (e.getSource() == m) {

            ans = input * ans;
            updating.setText(ans + " ");
            zzz.setText("0 ");

        }

        if (e.getSource() == c) {
            ans = 0;
            updating.setText(" 0 ");
            zzz.setText(" 0");

        }

    }


}
```

I can use option for the message but how can I compare the two values and how to check if entered value is a string
do i use the textfieldgettext and compare it to float?i tried that but it shows the message each time i type something in the textfield

i can use option pane and use the confirm message but it shows for each entry i type

Comment: JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog
(this,"enter valid value!"," enter valid value ",
JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
 this is the part  of my code for the pop up message

Comment: how do i know if the value entered in the textfield is a string and not a number